# Can you change the workspace for a jenkins job using the GitHub Source Branch Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm building an MSBuild project on jenkins, using the GitHub Source Branch Plugin to trigger builds when a pull request is created.

My builds are failing with the error `error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file <filename>. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

Part of the problem is our developers like to write deep directory structures with long directory names.  But, the other part of the problem is that the workspace has a 52-digit hash as part of the directory name.

I don't see this hash in other jenkins jobs, so I'm assuming the GitHub Source Branch Plugin is setting this.  Is there any way I can use a shorter directory name?